# Custom view class in an external lib not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am using an external library (jar) that contains a custom view class.  I have to test projects using it.  One is working and one is not.

The non-working one has the following error in Eclipse on the line that references the custom view:

`error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'bar' in package 'com.example.testapp'`

For reference, the layout looks like this (simplified):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foolib="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.customviewlib.MyBarImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        foolib:bar="test.bar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The only difference between the two projects seems to be that the working project has a package under "gen" called "com.example.customviewlib" (with an R.java).  Ie. matching the library package name.

Am I right in assuming that it is the missing gen package for the library that is the reason the custom view is not working in my second project?

If so how do I force the package to be generated in my other project?

I have tried various suggestions such as cleaning the project and restarting Eclipse.

Comment: How did you import the jar in the non-working project?

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  Discovered the problem.  You can't currently (as of ADT 22 at least) use custom view classes directly from external jars.  You have to make an Android Library project and reference that.

It is basically the same reason that ActionBarSherlock has to be a library project.  You need access  to the resources (in my case res/values/attrs.xml etc) which aren't present in the jar.

Comment: Not that I am aware of (other than making a library project as stated), but I would love to be proved wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I think Google needs to work on this. It's really annoying to keep a separate project just for a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but you might be adding the jar through the *build path* in the non-working project, which is 'deprecated' since the last sdk versions.

If you just copy the jar in the `libs` folder, it should work fine.

Comment: I had tried both actually.  However I have just discovered the problem (see my answer)